# Count lines in ASCII file using C

Tags: c, ascii, text-files

I would like to count the number of lines in an ASCII text file.
I thought the best way to do this would be by counting the newlines in the file:

```
for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {  /* Count word line endings. */
    if (c == '\n') ++lines;
}
```

However, I'm not sure if this would account for the last line on all both MS Windows and Linux. That is if my text file finishes as below, without an explicit newline, is there one encoded there anyway or  should I add an extra `++lines;` after the for loop?

```
cat
dog
```

Then what about if there *is* an explicit newline at the end of the file? Or do I just need to test for this case by keeping track of the previously read value?

Comment: That's an interesting file reading approach using the `for` loop.  I've never approached it quite that way.

Comment: You are right about doubting your approach. Since the `EOF` overwrites the last read value, you'd need to save that somewhere else. Does a file that contains just a single `\n` contain one or two lines?

Comment: Well, it depends whether the newline actually _is_ there. If create a document with Notepad, it won't do it, but maybe some editors will. You could check if the last character in the document is a newline and act accordingly.

Comment: (For clarity of this particular question, you may want to rename `words` to `lines`. Unless `line == word`, in which case you may need a different approach.)

Comment: Just realised I could probably just use fgets()! Only concern then is speed... is fgets() any slwoer than my char-by-char approach?

Comment: `fgets` is likely to be faster on some platforms because of the stream locking stream scheme and function call overhead.  But you will still need to scan the buffer for '\n' in case you have a line longer than the buffer size, and handling the last line will be even more complicated because of that.  Keep it simple.

Comment: So: `while (fgets(line, LENGTH+1, fp) == NULL){ if (line[0]!='\0') { ++lines;}}` is my code now :)

Comment: problems: `LENGTH+1` is suspicious.  `words[0]` should be initialized to `'\n'` to avoid counting 1 for the empty file.  Most serious of all: **lines longer than LENGTH will be split and counted multiple times**.  The simple `getc()` loop is more reliable and probably just as fast.

Comment: If you define a line to be an optional string delimited by a newline, then according to that definition any trailing content is not a line. If you define what **you** mean with line differently, it can be different. In any case, make sure you don't forget to consider cornercases like empty lines, empty files or files without newlines.

Comment: POSIX.1-2017 Ch. 3, definition 206 offers a definition of a line:  `3.206 Line
A sequence of zero or more non- <newline> characters plus a terminating <newline> character.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no newline, one won't be generated. C tells you exactly what's there.

Comment: Almost true: C tells you there is a `'\n'` whereas the files really contain `'\r'`, `'\n'` in Windows.

Comment: @chqrlie unless you open it in `b` mode

Answer (score 3):

Text files are always expected to end with a line feed. There's no canonical way of handling files that don't.

Here's how some tools choose to deal with characters after the last line feed:

- `wc` doesn't count it as a line (so you have good precedence for that)
- Vim marks the file as `[noeol]`, and saves the file without a trailing line feed
- GNU `sed` treats the file as if it had a last line feed
- `sh`'s `read` exits with error, but still returns the data

Since behaviour is pretty much undefined, you can just do whatever's convenient or useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

First, there will not be any implicitly encoded newline at the end of the last line. The only way there will be a newline is if the software or person that produced the file put it there. Putting it there is generally considered good practice, however.

The ultimate answer for what you should report as the line count depends on the convention that you need to follow for the software or people that will be using this line count, and probably what you can assume about the behavior of the input source as well.

Most command-line tools will terminate their output with a newline character. In this case, the sensible answer may be to report the number of newline characters as the number of actual lines.

On the other hand, when a text editor is displaying a file, you will see that the line numbering in the margin (if supported) contains a number for the last line whether it is empty or not. This is in part to tell the user that there is a blank line there, but if you want to count the number of lines displayed in the margin, it is one plus the number of newline characters in the file. It is typical for some coders to not terminate their last lines with a newline character (sometimes due to sloppiness), so in this case this convention would actually be the right answer.

I'm not sure any other conventions make much sense. For example, if you choose not to count the last line unless it is non-empty, then what counts as non-empty? The file ending after newline? What if there is whitespace on that line? What if there are several empty lines at the end of the file?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use this method, you could always keep a separate counter for how many letters on the line you are at. If the count at the end is greater than 1, then you know there is stuff on the last line that wasn't counted.

```
int letters = 0

for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {  /* Count word line endings. */
    letters++; // Increase count on character

    if (c == '\n')
    {
        ++words;
        letters = 0; // Set back to 0 after new line
    }
}

if (letters > 0)
{
    ++words;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is real, the last line in the file may be missing the final end of line marker.  The end of line marker is a single `'\n'` in Linux, a CR LF pair in Windows that the C runtime converts automatically into a `'\n'`.

You can simplify your code and handle the special case of the last line missing a linefeed this way:

```
int c, last = '\n', lines = 0;

while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {  /* Count word line endings. */
    if (c == '\n')
        lines += 1;
    last = c;
}
if (last != '\n')
    lines += 1;
```

Since you are concerned with speed, using `getc` instead of `fgetc` will help on platforms where it is defined as a macro that handles the stream structures directly and calls a function only to refill the buffer, every `BUFSIZ` characters or so, unless the stream is unbuffered.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Create a flag for yourself to keep track of any non `\n` characters following a `\n` that is reset when `c=='\n'`.
After the `EOF`, check to see if the flag is true and increment if yes.

```
bool more_chars = false;
for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {  /* Count word line endings. */
            if (c == '\n') {
              more_chars = false;
              ++words;
            } else more_chars = true;
 }
 if(more_chars) words++;
```

Answer (score -1):

Windows and UNIX/Linux style line breaks make no difference here. On either system a text file may or may not have a newline at the end of the last line.

If you always add 1 to the line count, this effectively counts the empty line at the end of the file when there *is* a newline at the end (i.e., file `"foo\n"` will count as having two lines: `"foo"` and `""`). This may be an entirely reasonable solution, depending on how you want to define a line.

Another definition of a "line" is that it always ends in a newline, i.e., the file `"foo\nbar"` would only have one line (`"foo"`) by this definition. This definition is used by `wc`.

Of course you could keep track of whether the newline was the last character in file and only add 1 to the count in case it wasn't. Then a "line" would be defined as either ending in a newline or being non-empty at the end of the file, which sounds quite complex to me.

Comment: This would also generate a line count of 1 on a completely empty file, though.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yes, "the empty line at the end of the file" would be the only line in that special case. It's kind of a philosophical question whether an empty file still has one line (or if an empty file even counts as a "text file" since there is no text). =)

Comment: No philosophy here: A file with a single byte `'\n'` has a single line, en empty file has no lines. no lines obviously means `lines = 0`.  The philosophical question might be: why is there a plural in *no lines* instead of *no line*?

Comment: @chqrlie You've are just assuming one definition of line as the only correct one. From a programmer's perspective I think the simplest definition of a line is indeed "a line always ends in a linefeed", but that leaves the question of how many lines do the files `"foo\nbar"` (`wc` says 1) or `"foo"` (`wc` says 0) have.

Comment: @chqrlie I would generally agree that the empty file has no lines, but on the other hand in many text editors the empty file is shown as having one line when opened. Also, if one were to say that the file `"foo"` (no linefeed) has 1 line and the file `"foo\n\nbar"` has 3 lines, then it would seem to follow quite simply that the file `""` has 1 line (but as discussed earlier, it's valid to say that these files have 0, 2, and 0 lines, respectively). As for philosophy, can you call an empty field a forest with 0 trees? =)

Comment: The issue on the incomplete last line is documented this way in `man wc`: *A line is defined as a string of characters delimited by a <newline> character.  Characters beyond the final <newline> character will not be included in the line count.*  I agree the OP has to be precise in his specification of the *number of lines* in a file.

Comment: Regarding the text editor display for an empty file, the fact it shows a cursor on line 1 merely indicates that insertion can be performed there.  My own editor is quite clear on that: it displays `0 lines, point on line 1.  0 bytes on disk.`, but different editors may act differently, especially regarding the insertion of a final '\n' when saving the file.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, pretty much my entire point is that one needs to be clear about the definition of a line, and that there are multiple valid definitions. `wc` is very clear of its definition and I think it's a perfectly valid, it's just that not counting the incomplete last line may be counter-intuitive when the last line is non-empty (and especially if it's the only line). Meanwhile counting an incomplete last line leads to a more complex definition of a line if the empty incomplete last line is made a special case.